# Why is the number converted to a string (basic Javascript function)

Tags: javascript

I have this function (going trough the Eloquent Javascript Tutorial chapter 3):

```
function absolute(number) {

  if (number < 0)
  return -number;
  else
  return number;
}
```

show(absolute(prompt("Pick a number", "")));

If I run it and enter -3 the output will be 3 as expectet but if I enter just 3 the output will be "3" (with double quotes). I can get around by changing

```
return number;
```

to
    return Number(number);

but why is that necessary? What am I missing?

Comment: @mgraph: Try `parseInt("042")`

Comment: @NickBeranek: It's octal.  You need to force it to parse as decimal by adding `, 10`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`prompt()` always returns a string, but when you enter a negative number, it is handed to the `-number` call and implicitly converted to a `Number`. That doesn't happen if you pass it a positive, and the value received by `prompt()` is returned directly.

You can, as you discovered, cast it with  `Number()`, or you can use `parseInt(number, 10)`, or you could do `-(-number)` to flip it negative, then positive again, or more obviously as pointed out in comments, `+number`. (Don't do `--number`, which will cast it to a Number then decrement it)

Comment: @SLaks Indeed, Overcomplication is my middle name.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is not strongly typed.

`number` comes from the `prompt()` function, which returns a string.
Since you aren't doing anything to change its type, it remains a string.

`-number` implicitly converts and returns an actual number.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a string that needs to be converted to a number, please do the following:

```
var numString = '3';
var num = parseInt(numString);
console.log(num); // 3
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript performs automatic conversion between types. Your incoming "number" is most likely string (you can verify by showing result of `typeof(number)`).

`-` does not take "string" as argument, so it will be converted to number first and than negated. You can get the same behavior using unary `+`: `typeof(+ "3")` is number when `typeof("3")` is string.

Same happens for binary `-` - will convert operands to number. `+` is more fun as it work with both strings `"1"+"2"` is "12", but `1+2` is 3.